# How should I be backing up Postgres for this scenario?

Tags: postgresql, backup, pg-dump

So the way I have been backing up Postgres is with:

```
pg_dumpall -U eox-dev -h localhost --clean --file=/home/backups/postgres.sql
```

I want to make sure I have a production ready backup that has functions, relationships, triggers, in addition to tables and data.

I'm trying to restore it now in a Kubernetes cluster into a database with a different name `prod_db` -> `staging_db`, but get `FATAL: database "prod_db" does not exist`. I'm trying to restore it to `staging_db` so that makes sense. One of the first lines in the `.sql` does declare `CREATE DATABASE prod_db`. I'm not about the edit the `.sql`. If I have to do that, I'm doing something wrong.

What is the correct way of making this backup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to restore individual databases, you should probably be using `pg_dump`, not `pg_dumpall`.  And if you don't intend to restore over the top of an existing populated database, you shouldn't be using `--clean`.

Backing up your entire cluster and migrating/cloning one database that is in it are different tasks, you probably want different commands to do them.

But you have the dilemma that if you specify `--create` to pg_dump it will want to restore into a database of the same name as it dumped from, and if you don't specify `--create` then it is up to you to create a new database with the name you want, but also with the correct ENCODING and LOCALE.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that pg_dump or pg_dumpall or pg_restore can change the database name to be restored. However after restoring the database (with the same name) you can rename it with:

```
alter database old rename to new;
```